# Перемешать массивы по парам Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Помогите пожалуйста решить простую задачу.

**Задача:** Разбить массив по парам и вывести в html

В моем варианте я могу перемешать массив и вывести результат в консоль, но почему-то в html блок выводит только последний элемент.

Вопрос: подскажите как вывести весь перемешанный массив в html блок по парам.

```js
let pairs = $('.pairs')

pairs.click(function(){

  let names = ['Ваня', 'Петя', 'Степа', 'Маша', 'Катя'];
  
  $.each(names, function(index, value){
  
    function shuffle(value) {
              names.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
            }
            
            shuffle(value);
        
         console.log(value, index);
     $('.result').html(value)
  })
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="result"></div>
<button class="pairs">Перемешать</button>
```

Comment: @PavelNazarian Попробовал, если вашим вариантом он выводит массив как и был. Но есть я беру `$('.result').append(names)` то он выводит 4 раза перемешанный массив. Какие варианты есть улучшить?

Comment: А что значит перемешать по парам?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я просто описал всю задачу. Но проблема была в том что не мог вывести все в html блок. Дальше нужно разбить перемешанный массив на пары, но это хочу сам сделать.

Comment: .........окей))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let pairs = $('.pairs')

pairs.click(function(){
  let names = ['Ваня', 'Петя', 'Степа', 'Маша', 'Катя'];
  
  $.each(names, function(index, value){
        function shuffle(value) {
            names.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        }

        shuffle(value);                      
  })
  
  $('.result').html(names.join(' '));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="result"></div>
<button class="pairs">Перемешать</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!